# Pre-scroll CSS is different than post scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Sliding working Fiddle but incorrect width prior to scroll is [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/chrisfrisina/An39n/).  Correct layout, but no scroll functionality is [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/chrisfrisina/An39n/1/).  Still learning CSS, but for some reason, if I remove the follwong fixed floating side CSS:

```
#commentWrapper { 
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 35px;
  left: 450px;
  width: 280px;
}

#comment {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  /* Can include margins in the sliding effect here */
}

#comment.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

, the position is correct for the side, however it does no stay at its fixed postion as you scroll down.   keeping the code in, the CSS for some reason reduces the width of the side,  but as soon as you scroll down, it becomes normal.   How can I fix it so that it loads on the side with the correct position and width?

Comment: I was gonna say it could be related to the new Lion's scrollbars, but I just tested in windows and the problem is there too. It seems to be related to the relative widths you are using. If you use a fixed width for the `<aside>`, the problem goes away.

Comment: still not oriented in a similar fashion as with the three CSS portions removed, so it seems to be in those 3 ID selectors, just not sure how to interact them correctly with the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your CSS.  [Take a look](http://fiddle.jshell.net/An39n/3/).  I hope this fixed your problem!

The relevant code I changed:

New:

```
#commentWrapper { 
float:right;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-right: 10px;
left: 450px;
width: 25%;
}
```

Old:

```
#commentWrapper { 
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 35px;
    left: 450px;
    width: 280px;
}
```

Comment: it fixed the fiddle, not my page, but it pointed me in the right direction to fix mine.   Thanks